# Почему не выводятся страницы в Windows SQL и нет доступа

Tags: sql, windows

Почему не выводятся страницы в Windows SQL Server и нет доступа, когда загружаю сайты. Что делать, нужен сайт на Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не предоставлен доступ к папке с данными сайта, нужно разрешить доступ группе IIS_IUSRS

Comment: какой вопрос такой и ответ, видимо

Comment: а где это сделать

Comment: нашел где добавлять но нет такого пользователя

Comment: ой перепутал с линукс, на винде нужно добавить группу IIS_IUSRS и всё должно работать

Comment: @СеменНемяев если у вас вэб-сервер IIS, то там пользователь `IUSR`, но поскольку ваш вопрос ничего толком не конкретизирует, то и абстрактный ответ вам мало чем поможет.

Comment: @JohnnyMc Спасибо!!!! получилось